# Seeking an algorithm to turn a continues signal into binary

Tags: classification, signal-processing

I had a nice project in mind, which I will probably not going to do because of a lack of time, but I had some theoretical problem I faced there, which still bother me and might be interesting for you too.

I have a data from an animal, which moves in a discrete way. It move for few frames and then stop for few frames and keep going.

I have the distances between each successive frames of the tip of the tail of the animal. For example if we had 5 frames, I have a list of length of 4, the first value is the Euclidean distance between the tip of its tail in the first frame to the tip of the tail in the second frame, the second value is the distance between the second frame and the third frame and so on..

I believe when the animal is moving the distance is greater then it stays in the place (There is no affect of a dog wagging its tail) and I have an assumption that a movement, and the inter bouts interval are longer then a single frame. Units of movement are irrelevant of course.

Given that signal I wish to tell in which frames was the animal moving. Let examine a plot for example:

[image]

My first attempt was to use a Gaussian filter, this would look roughly like this:

[image]

Now taking a median as a threshold might work, but looks like it can leads to some bad decisions, like the last 2 bouts might be separated, might be not. Looking in the original graph make me think they are separated. I am not sure this method is getting the best from it.

What do you think? any ideas?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to say. If the animal is moving, than it changes position, so I do not really see what is here to calculate besides difference between positions on subsequent frames?

Comment: I computed the differences, but I assume in each frame the animal is moving or not moving, its binary. You can see such kind of movements here for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnGWPK7-Odg

Comment: After I got the distances, I want to make my signal into binary, so I have phases of movements and phases of staying in place. This seems simple, but not so trivial

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. "Not moving" seems to be in same spot as in previous frame, isn't it?

Comment: When the fish stays still, consider not moving (I wish to label that frame as 0). But my actual signal is not 0, but relative lower numbers, cause of noise/ miniature movements I don't count. In a frame the fish is moving (I wish to label 1) my signal gets higher values. The question is how to determine the threshold, and should any other operation should be done, such as filtering, etc..

Comment: Well, this is a question you should ask *yourself*. How much move would you count as "moving"? Empirically, you can use something like x% quantile.